# My picture is not below the menu on the left

Tags: html, css

I'm a new student in the web development world. I am trying to create a static page for personal study and I need to leave the image to the left well below the menu, however, I have already tried the forms that I know and all continue to present the same error, so I believe someone here can answer me. Can someone help me?

https://ibb.co/M8rsp49

This is the html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="shortcun icon" type="image/x-png" href="_imagens/icone-adv6.png"/>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">         
        <!-- inicio menu -->
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="_imagens/iconadv6.png"></a>
        </div>
        <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><p class="gilroy-bold">equipe</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><p class="gilroy-bold">cases</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><p class="gilroy-bold">agência</p></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        <!-- fim menu -->
    </header>
   <div class="zoom">
        <img  src="_imagens/predio.png">
        <div class="text-item">
    </div>
    <div id="tituloadv6">
        <h1><p class="gilroy-bold">Somos a <br />ADV6</h1></p>
    </div>
    <div id="texto1">
        <h3><p class="gilroy-bold">Não fazemos a menor ideia. <br />Fazemos a maior.</h3></a>
    </div>
    <div id="texto2">
        <p class="gilroy-bold">Passa aqui! <br/> Tem playstation, café, <br />cerveja e muita criatividade. </a>
    </div>  


</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "gilroy-bold";
  src: url("../_fonts/gilroy-bold.ttf");
}

.gilroy-bold{ 
  font-family: "gilroy-bold";
}

.header ul li a:hover {
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FF8C00;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.zoom {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom img {
  max-width: 90%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.zoom:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#tituloadv6{
  margin-left: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
#logo{
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 15px;

}

#texto1{
  padding-left: 100px;
}
#texto2{
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
.header{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav{
  width: 100%;
}
ul{
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  float: right;
}
.logo img{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
nav a{
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

changing `float: right` to `float: left` and `margin-top: 40px` to `margin-top: 100px`

```
.zoom img {
  max-width: 90%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: set up a working script in codepen.io or similar websites and people may help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.zoom` class to this:

```
.zoom {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then change the float of the `img` tag:

```
.zoom img {
    .zoom img {
     max-width: 90%;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
     transition: all 0.3s;
     float: left;
     margin-top: 40px;
     position: relative;
}
```

You'll need to change the margins of the text to make sure text is readable.

See this codepen for more details: https://codepen.io/aharish-the-typescripter/pen/GPqqpw

Comment: Thank you. This way it worked. But the text went down, how can I fix it? https://ibb.co/rtKCpQb

Comment: If you want the text overlayed above the image, give the `.zoom` class `position: relative;`, and it's child elements `position: absolute;`. You can then adjust the `top` value of the text as needed.